# If you include something in the .h file Do you have to include the same thing again?

Tags: c++, c, intellij-idea

So I am just wondering if you `#include something` in a for example header.h file:

For example this is called `header.h`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <somethingElse>
```

So if for example I make a file called `something.cpp` Do I need to put all those include statements again?

```
#include "header.h"
// If I include #header.h in this file. Do the #include carry over to this file. Or do they not
```

I am wondering because whenever I include `<vector>` something in my .h file the `#include` statements that I used previously in the `.h` file always turn grey which means they are not used. Is it because I used it in the `.h` file? Its not a problem or anything I am just curious.

Comment: When you include a file, it's essentially the same as copying the contents of the file in place of the `#include` line. That's true for `#include` lines in the header file, just like anything else. So if the header file includes `<vector>`, it's redundant to include it again in your file.

Comment: All the standard header files are designed so that including them extra times has no effect, that's why the IDE shows it as not used.

Comment: I think this other question & answer addresses this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963143/headers-include-in-multiple-c-files (at least for C)

Comment: Also there are header guards.

Comment: @Digits That's a different issue.

Comment: More info https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262019/is-it-good-practice-to-rely-on-headers-being-included-transitively

Comment: @Digits This question is about including the same file in a translation unit both directly and indirectly. That question is about including a file in different translation units that will eventually be linked together.

Comment: For a counter-argument that you should explicitly include headers for features you explicitly use, even if those headers also come along for a ride with other headers in the current system, see the [Include What You Use (IWYU)](https://include-what-you-use.org/) project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to include those headers again because your compiler can find those headers. You can also try to read and understand the [makefile (or CMakeList)](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) which will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try always to avoid "Multiple file inclusion" via using `inclusion guard` or `#pragma once` in order to prevent the multiple file inclusion.

To include file means that the content of the file will be added to the very place you wrote include.

Here's an example:

```
// header.h
const int vlaue = 10;
const int value2 = 0;

// main.cpp

#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"
```

Above the content of "header.h" is added twice to main.cpp.

Do you know what is the result? It's a compile-time error complaining of redefinition of `value` and `value2`.

In the above example I think green programmers don't get trapped by it but it is just an explanation, So what I talk about is when a huge program where many header files and many source files and some files include others then it'll be so difficult to track the right file inclusion.

The workaround that is to use `inclusion guards` or `pragma once` eg:

Let's modify our `header.h` to look like:

```
// header.h

#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

const int vlaue  = 10;
const int value2 = 0;

#endif
```

Now in main.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"
```

The code above works fine and no duplicate of header content is added to main.cpp. Do you know why? It's the magic of Macro there. So at first time the pre-processor checks whether a macro has been already defined with the name `MY_HEADER_H` or not and for sure for the first time it is not defined so the content is added. The second and so on the condition fails because the macro is already defined thus the content of header.h will not be added to where it is called.

The draw back of inclusion guard is if you have a macro with same name as the inclusion guard thus it is already defined so the content will never be added (empty content). Thus you get a compile-time error:

```
value, `value2` undeclared identifiers.
```

The second solution is using `pragma` eg:

Let's modify our header.h file:

```
// header.h
#pragma once

const int vlaue = 10;
const int value2 = 0;

// main.cpp

#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"
```

The code above works correctly so no multiple inclusion of header.h That is because of the magic of `pragma once`: which is a non-standard but widely supported pre-processor directive designed to cause the current source file to be included only once in a single compilation. Thus, #pragma once serves the same purpose as include guards, but with several advantages, including: less code, avoidance of name clashes, and sometimes improvement in compilation speed.

- Finally you should include header wherever their content is used eg:

  ```
  // Shape.h

  class Shape{
      // some code here
  };

  // Cube.h

  #include "Shape.h"

  class Cube : public Shape{
       // some code here
  };

  // Cuboid.h

  // #include "Shape.h" 
  #include "Cube.h" // So here the Shape.h is added to Cube.h and Cube.h is added here.

  class Cuboid : public Cube{
     // some code here
  };
  ```
- As you can see above the content of Shape.h is added to Cuboid.h indirectly because it is added to Cube.h and cuboid.h includes Cube.h so it is added to it. So without inclusion guards or pragma once if you include the two headers in one source file you get duplicate content there.